# How wso2 api manager validates whether application is subscribed to API or not when the request comes

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How wso2 api manager validates whether application is subscribed to API or not when the request comes. Does keymanager validate that via an API call or Gateway does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How wso2 api manager validates whether application is subscribed to
>   API or not when the request comes?

When you invoke an API, you have to send an OAuth 2 token, WSO2 API Manager validates the subscription based on that token.

> Does keymanager validate that via an API call or Gateway does that?

Gateway validate the token via a service call to Key Manager. Also, both Gateway and Key Manager have a cache in their own.

Comment: How it validates the subscription from the token. The token does not contain any subscription information. Is key manager validates the token and getting the client id from the validation and then request for validate the subscription from DB or store?

Comment: @Palle Indeed, the token information (application, user, ..) is loaded from DB and this information is cached as well